# vba sql query in MS Access

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, search

I have created a form for searching data by keyword, and assign this vba code to button's click event:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT MD.[id], MD.[status], MD.[milnum], MD.[sname], MD.[mother], MD.[grade], MD.[gradetype], MD.[spcode], MD.[spes], MD.[unit] FROM MD WHERE (MD.[status] LIKE '*" & Me.tstate & "*') AND (MD.[milnum] LIKE '*" & Me.tnumber & "*') AND (MD.[sname] LIKE '*" & Me.tname & "*') AND (MD.[mother] LIKE '*" & Me.tmother & "*') AND (MD.[grade] LIKE '*" & Me.tgrade & "*') AND (MD.[gradetype] LIKE '*" & Me.ttype & "*') AND (MD.[spcode] LIKE '*" & Me.tcode & "*') AND (MD.[spes] LIKE '*" & Me.tspes & "*') AND (MD.[unit] LIKE '*" & Me.tunit & "*')order by MD.[id]"

Me.MD_Sheet.Form.RecordSource = sql
Me.MD_Sheet.Form.Requery
```

But when I doing a search, the query doesn't bring all results, for example when I write nothing in the textboxex it should brings all records from table MD but it doesn't, it just brings some records.

I create another button and assign  same code to 'click event' with new sql statement:

```
Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT MD.[id], MD.[status], MD.[milnum], MD.[sname], MD.[mother], MD.[grade], MD.[gradetype], MD.[spcode], MD.[spes], MD.[unit] FROM MD"
    Me.MD_Sheet.Form.RecordSource = sql
    Me.MD_Sheet.Form.Requery
```

And then it brings all records.

The records in MD  table are about 25000 records.

Comment: Is the sql query statement length affect the results. I use multi like clause.

Comment: Just leaving one criteria empty won't bring all records. The other criteria are still applied and records are filtered. I prefer to have VBA construct filter criteria only with controls that have input. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: @June7 sorry but i edited the question and forgot the rest of it to edit. I leav all of the criterias empty.

Comment: _it should brings all records from table MD_ - and it will, but only if the field holds a value; _Null_ is excluded.

Comment: @Gustav how to fix that if the field holds Null?

Comment: I solve this problem by replacing all null fields with space " ". And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying *Nz*, not fast but simple:

```
AND (Nz(MD.[spcode]) LIKE '*" & Me.tcode & "*')
```

Comment: What is (Nz) do? What is mean?

Comment: [Nz](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.nz?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: It does. If not, something else is going on.